# Using Textboxfor or Editorfor a property that is part of a list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

I have a model that contains a list of `Organization` called `Organizations`. Each `Organization` has a `Name` and a `Number`.

In order for the model to be binded automatically on submitting the form, I need to give each text box a specific name following a naming convention I found from several tutorials (look at `namePrefix` in the code).

However, I would rather use `Html.TextboxFor` rather than `Html.Textbox`, so that it will use the data attributes and validation. How can I get Html.TextboxFor to use the naming convention I need?

```
<%
    int orgIndex = 0;
    foreach(Organization org in Model.Organizations)
    { 
        string namePrefix = String.Format("Organizations[{0}].", orgIndex++);
        %>


    <%= Html.TextBox(namePrefix + "Name" , org.Name) %> 

    <%= Html.TextBox(namePrefix + "Number", org.Number) %>


<%  } %>
```

Here's my model...

```
 public class User
 {
      [ListMinLength(1)]
      public List<Organization> Organizations;
 }

 public class Organization
{
    [Display(Prompt = "COMMON_DEALER_NAME", ResourceType = typeof(Modules.Properties.Resources))]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Prompt = "DEALER_ID_PLACEHOLDER", ResourceType = typeof(Modules.Properties.Resources))]
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public long Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think I need to make a custom editor template, and use the EditorFor html helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let Razor handle this for you. Change your code to:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Model.Organizations.Count(); i++)
{ 
    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Organizations[i].Name) %> 

    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Organizations[i].Number) %>
}
```

Then the right names will be generated automatically.

Comment: Thanks. Is it using reflection on the expression to know it is part of a list?

Comment: This doesn't work for validation messages unfortunately.

Comment: Yes it does. It would follow the same format: `Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Organizations[i].Name)`

Comment: Hmm. The model state doesn't contain any keys for the Organizations.